# Why in the Design Timing Summery (synthesis) in Vivado i get WNS = inf?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I want to make sure that my program works with a clock of at least 100ns. I have already set the timing constraint.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

WNS=INF typically means ~ you do not have/ did not setup a clock.

Maybe you dont need a clock - is your circuit all combinatorial? If so, need to add registers and clock to get timing report to report a timed path.

If you circuit has FFs, clk and such already - make sure you tell Vivado (or Quartus) that your clock exists and is a specific frequency - some kind of create_clock constraint.